# Basic array build

Tags: php, arrays

Guess this is a basic question.
How can I make an array similar to this, using a foreach loop?

```
          [
            [
                'ProductGuid' => '27760c24',
                'BaseAmountValue' => 240,
                'Quantity' => 1,
                'Discount' => 0,
                'AccountNumber' => 1000,
                'Unit' => 'parts',
            ],
            [
                'ProductGuid' => '27760c24',
                'BaseAmountValue' => 250,
                'Quantity' => 1,
                'Discount' => 0,
                'AccountNumber' => 1000,
                'Unit' => 'parts',
            ]
        ],
```

The following is rejected by the API, i'm trying to connect to:

```
        $arr = array();
        foreach($items as $item) {
            $arr[]['ProductGuid'] = $item->guid;
            $arr[]['BaseAmountValue'] = $item->price;
            $arr[]['Quantity'] = $item->qty;
            $arr[]['Discount'] = $item->discount;
            $arr[]['AccountNumber'] = 1000;
            $arr[]['Unit'] = 'parts';
        }
```

Hope one of you will be able to help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to the other two correct answers but without manually setting the array index or use any temporary variables:

```
$arr = [];
foreach($items as $item) {
    $arr[] = [
        'ProductGuid'     => $item->guid,
        'BaseAmountValue' => $item->price,
        'Quantity'        => $item->qty,
        'Discount'        => $item->discount,
        'AccountNumber'   => 1000,
        'Unit'            => 'parts',
    ];
}
```

[Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3536236/martin) explained the actual issue so well so no need to go through it again.

Answer (score 3):

Using the given code, you create **new** inner rows in your array in each line of that loop. The following code will solve that:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($items as $item) {
     $mappedItem = [];
     $mappedItem['ProductGuid'] = $item->guid;
     $mappedItem['BaseAmountValue'] = $item->price;
     $mappedItem['Quantity'] = $item->qty;
     $mappedItem['Discount'] = $item->discount;
     $mappedItem['AccountNumber'] = 1000;
     $mappedItem['Unit'] = 'parts';
     $arr[] = $mappedItem;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're fairly close to *one* way of doing this...

## Explanation:

> ```
> $arr[]['ProductGuid'] = $item->guid;
>     ^^
>     \= Next numeric array key.
> ```

What this is doing is setting the `productGuid` key on the *next* numeric outer array, so in effect what you're actually setting is:

```
$arr[0]['ProductGuid'] = $item->guid;
$arr[1]['BaseAmountValue'] = $item->price;
$arr[2]['Quantity'] = $item->qty;
$arr[3]['Discount'] = $item->discount;
$arr[4]['AccountNumber'] = 1000;
$arr[5]['Unit'] = 'parts';
```

Which is clearly not what you want.

## One Solution:

Therefore you will have to set the array key value on each iteration of the `foreach` loop.

One way of doing this is manually setting an *iterator* integer key value:

```
$arr = [];
$x = 0;     
foreach($items as $item) {         
    $arr[$x]['ProductGuid'] = $item->guid;
    $arr[$x]['BaseAmountValue'] = $item->price;
    $arr[$x]['Quantity'] = $item->qty;
    $arr[$x]['Discount'] = $item->discount;
    $arr[$x]['AccountNumber'] = 1000;
    $arr[$x]['Unit'] = 'parts';
    $x++; // +1 to value of $x
}
```

**Edit:**
[Nico's way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61733097/3536236) of doing this is a bit neater and a bit smarter.